# Passing an array to a query using a WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql

Given an array of ids `$galleries = array(1,2,5)` I want to have a SQL query that uses the values of the array in its WHERE clause like:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM galleries
WHERE id = /* values of array $galleries... eg. (1 || 2 || 5) */
```

How can I generate this query string to use with MySQL?

Comment: A few modern/secure/stable alternatives using mysqli are elsewhere on Stack Overflow:  [Use an array in a mysqli prepared statement: `WHERE .. IN(..)` query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71718174/2943403) and [mysqli bind_param for array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58355651/2943403)

Answer (score 357, accepted):

> **BEWARE!** This answer contains a severe [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) vulnerability. Do NOT use the code samples as presented here, without making sure that any external input is sanitized.

```
$ids = join("','",$galleries);   
$sql = "SELECT * FROM galleries WHERE id IN ('$ids')";
```

Comment: There were a lot of impassioned comments on this from both angles of SQL injection. The TL;DR here is that this answer DOES work, but, because it takes those raw values and puts them into SQL directly, if the upstream data is untrusted you COULD be opening yourself up to a SQL injection attack. There are other answers to this question that enumerate how to avoid that problem.

Answer (score 327):

**Using PDO:**<sup>[1]</sup>

```
$in = join(',', array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));
$select = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM galleries
    WHERE id IN ($in);
SQL;
$statement = $pdo->prepare($select);
$statement->execute($ids);
```

**Using MySQLi** <sup>[2]</sup>

```
$in = join(',', array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));
$select = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM galleries
    WHERE id IN ($in);
SQL;
$statement = $mysqli->prepare($select);
$statement->bind_param(str_repeat('i', count($ids)), ...$ids);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->get_result();
```

---

Explanation:

#### Use the SQL `IN()` operator to check if a value exists in a given list.

In general it looks like this:

```
expr IN (value,...)
```

We can build an expression to place inside the `()` from our array. Note that there must be at least one value inside the parenthesis or MySQL will return an error; this equates to making sure that our input array has at least one value. To help prevent against SQL injection attacks, first generate a `?` for each input item to create a parameterized query. Here I assume that the array containing your ids is called `$ids`:

```
$in = join(',', array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));

$select = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM galleries
    WHERE id IN ($in);
SQL;
```

Given an input array of three items `$select` will look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM galleries
WHERE id IN (?, ?, ?)
```

Again note that there is a `?` for each item in the input array. Then we'll use PDO or MySQLi to prepare and execute the query as noted above.

#### Using the `IN()` operator with strings

It is easy to change between strings and integers because of the bound parameters. For PDO there is no change required; for MySQLi change `str_repeat('i',` to `str_repeat('s',` if you need to check strings.

<sup><sup>[1]:</sup> I've omitted some error checking for brevity. You need to check for the usual errors for each database method (or set your DB driver to throw exceptions).</sup>

<sup><sup>[2]:</sup> Requires PHP 5.6 or higher. Again I've omitted some error checking for brevity.</sup>

Comment: Can anyone clear up what the "..." does or is supposed to be in the mysqli statement?

Comment: If you are referring to `$statement->bind_param(str_repeat('i', count($ids)), ...$ids);` then the `...` is expanding the id's from an array into multiple parameters. If you are referring to `expr IN (value,...)` then that just means that there can be more values eg `WHERE id IN (1, 3, 4)`. There just needs to be at least one.

Comment: I was confused what <<< was but I found a reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: Also, here is the reference for the `...` : http://wiki.php.net/rfc/argument_unpacking

Answer (score 61):

ints:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `$table` WHERE `$column` IN(".implode(',',$array).")";
```

strings:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `$table` WHERE `$column` IN('".implode("','",$array)."')";
```

Answer (score 31):

Assuming you properly sanitize your inputs beforehand...

```
$matches = implode(',', $galleries);
```

Then just adjust your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM galleries
WHERE id IN ( $matches )
```

Quote values appropriately depending on your dataset.

Comment: I tried what you are proposing but it just fetched the first key value. I know it doesn't make sense, but if I do it using user542568 example, the damned thing works.

Answer (score 18):

Use:

```
select id from galleries where id in (1, 2, 5);
```

A simple `for each` loop will work.

[Flavius/AvatarKava's way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/907821/1003940) is better, but make sure that none of the array values contain commas.

Answer (score 10):

As [Flavius Stef's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/passing-an-array-to-a-query-using-a-where-clause/907821#907821), you can use `intval()` to make sure all `id` are int values:

```
$ids = join(',', array_map('intval', $galleries));  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM galleries WHERE id IN ($ids)";
```

Answer (score 7):

For [MySQLi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQLi) with an escape function:

```
$ids = array_map(function($a) use($mysqli) { 
    return is_string($a) ? "'".$mysqli->real_escape_string($a)."'" : $a;
  }, $ids);
$ids = join(',', $ids);  
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM galleries WHERE id IN ($ids)");
```

For PDO with prepared statement:

```
$qmarks = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM galleries WHERE id IN ($qmarks)");
$sth->execute($ids);
```

Comment: MySQLi has prepared statements too. Do not escape your input, this is potentially still vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 6):

We should take care of *[SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)* vulnerabilities and an *empty condition*. I am going to handle both as below.

For a pure numeric array, use the appropriate type conversion viz `intval` or `floatval` or `doubleval` over each element. For string types [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) which may also be applied to numeric values if you wish. *MySQL allows numbers as well as date variants as string*.

To appropriately escape the values before passing to the query, create a function similar to:

```
function escape($string)
{
    // Assuming $db is a link identifier returned by mysqli_connect() or mysqli_init()
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $string);
}
```

Such a function would most likely be already available to you in your application, or maybe you've already created one.

Sanitize the string array like:

```
$values = array_map('escape', $gallaries);
```

A numeric array can be sanitized using `intval` or `floatval` or `doubleval` instead as suitable:

```
$values = array_map('intval', $gallaries);
```

Then finally build the query condition

```
$where  = count($values) ? "`id` = '" . implode("' OR `id` = '", $values) . "'" : 0;
```

**or**

```
$where  = count($values) ? "`id` IN ('" . implode("', '", $values) . "')" : 0;
```

Since the array can also be empty sometimes, like `$galleries = array();` we should therefore note that `IN ()` does not allow for an empty list. One can also use `OR` instead, but the problem remains. So the above check, `count($values)`, is to ensure the same.

And add it to the final query:

```
$query  = 'SELECT * FROM `galleries` WHERE ' . $where;
```

> **TIP**: If you want to show all records (no filtering) in case of an empty array instead of hiding all rows, simply replace **0** with **1** in the ternary's false part.

Comment: To make my solution a one-liner *(and ugly one)*, just in case someone needs to:
`$query  = 'SELECT * FROM galleries WHERE ' . (count($gallaries) ? "id IN ('" . implode("', '", array_map('escape', $gallaries)) . "')" : 0);`

Answer (score 6):

Safe way without PDO:

```php
$ids = array_filter(array_unique(array_map('intval', (array)$ids)));

if ($ids) {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `galleries` WHERE `id` IN ('.implode(',', $ids).');';
}
```

- `(array)$ids` Cast `$ids` variable to array
- `array_map` Transform all array values into integers
- `array_unique` Remove repeated values
- `array_filter` Remove zero values
- `implode` Join all values to IN selection

Answer (score 5):

Safer.

```
$galleries = array(1,2,5);
array_walk($galleries , 'intval');
$ids = implode(',', $galleries);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM galleries WHERE id IN ($ids)";
```

Answer (score 5):

Col. Shrapnel's [SafeMySQL](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql) library for PHP provides type-hinted placeholders in its parametrised queries, and includes a couple of convenient placeholders for working with arrays. The `?a` placeholder expands out an array to a comma-separated list of escaped strings*.

For example:

```
$someArray = [1, 2, 5];
$galleries = $db->getAll("SELECT * FROM galleries WHERE id IN (?a)", $someArray);
```

* Note that since MySQL performs automatic type coercion, it doesn't matter that SafeMySQL will convert the ids above to strings - you'll still get the correct result.

Answer (score 4):

You may have table `texts` `(T_ID (int), T_TEXT (text))` and table `test` `(id (int), var (varchar(255)))`

In `insert into test values (1, '1,2,3') ;` the following will output rows from table texts where `T_ID IN (1,2,3)`:

```
SELECT * FROM `texts` WHERE (SELECT FIND_IN_SET( T_ID, ( SELECT var FROM test WHERE id =1 ) ) AS tm) >0
```

This way you can manage a simple n2m database relation without an extra table and using only SQL without the need to use PHP or some other programming language.

Answer (score 4):

We can use this "WHERE id IN" clause if we filter the input array properly. Something like this:

```
$galleries = array();

foreach ($_REQUEST['gallery_id'] as $key => $val) {
    $galleries[$key] = filter_var($val, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
}
```

Like the example below:[image]

```
$galleryIds = implode(',', $galleries);
```

I.e. now you should safely use `$query = "SELECT * FROM galleries WHERE id IN ({$galleryIds})";`

Comment: @levi-morrison posted a lot better solution to this.

Answer (score 3):

More an example:

```php
$galleryIds = [1, '2', 'Vitruvian Man'];
$ids = array_filter($galleryIds, function($n){return (is_numeric($n));});
$ids = implode(', ', $ids);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM galleries WHERE id IN ({$ids})";
// output: 'SELECT * FROM galleries WHERE id IN (1, 2)'

$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides using the IN query, you have two options to do so as in an IN query there is a risk of an SQL injection vulnerability. You can use **looping** to get the exact data you want or you can use the query with **OR** case

```
1. SELECT *
      FROM galleries WHERE id=1 or id=2 or id=5;


2. $ids = array(1, 2, 5);
   foreach ($ids as $id) {
      $data[] = SELECT *
                    FROM galleries WHERE id= $id;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the original question relates to an array of numbers and I am using an array of strings I couldn't make the given examples work.

I found that each string needed to be encapsulated in single quotes to work with the `IN()` function.

Here is my solution

```
foreach($status as $status_a) {
        $status_sql[] = '\''.$status_a.'\'';
    }
    $status = implode(',',$status_sql);

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($status)");
```

As you can see the first function wraps each array variable in `single quotes (\')` and then implodes the array.

NOTE: `$status` does not have single quotes in the SQL statement.

There is probably a nicer way to add the quotes but this works.

Comment: Or `$filter = "'" . implode("','",$status) . "'";`

Comment: This is injection-vulnerable.

Comment: Where is escaping of strings? For example `'` inside the string? SQL Injection vulnerable. Use PDO::quote or mysqli_real_escape_string.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the method I have used, using PDO with named placeholders for other data. To overcome SQL injection I am filtering the array to accept only the values that are integers and rejecting all others.

```
$owner_id = 123;
$galleries = array(1,2,5,'abc');

$good_galleries = array_filter($chapter_arr, 'is_numeric');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM galleries WHERE owner=:OWNER_ID AND id IN ($good_galleries)";
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(
    "OWNER_ID" => $owner_id,
));

$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: When you use `is_numeric()` so beware that  `0x539` is also a numeric value, so is `0b10100111001`