# Search array for values from database

Tags: php, database, arrays, search

I have a database filled with employee ID's and corresponding employee names for each employee ID. Is there a way I can search an array for employee ID's from the database? Google is not helping me, I think because I'm not sure how to word my search.

My idea is to have something like, array_search($empID, $currentArray). And then loop through each employee ID from the database, and compare it the $currentArray? I doubt this is the most efficient way but I am still learning so any help would be appreciated. If anyone is willing to take some time to help me with this I can post any more info needed. Thanks!

Edit here is my code if anyone is interested:

```
 <?php 

//this variable tells us how many drupal nodes or 'paystub pages' we need to create
$nodeCount = 0;
$i = 0;

//needed for creating a drupal node
//for this code to work this script must be run from the root of the drupal installation
require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

if ($handle = opendir('/var/www/html/pay.mistequaygroup.com/upload')) 
{

    /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) 
    {
       if ($file != "." && $file != "..") 
       {
            $nodeCount++;
            //We convert the pdf documents into text documents and move put them in the converted folder
            $command = "pdftotext /var/www/html/pay.mistequaygroup.com/upload/" . $file . " /var/www/html/pay.mistequaygroup.com/upload/converted/" . $file . ".txt";
            //Execute the command above
            $output = exec($command);

            //mark all the spots that TO THE ORDER OF shows up
            //echo array_search("TO THE ORDER OF", $currentArray);

            //echo $userName;


            //extract the employees name


            //print_r($currentArray);
            //echo '<pre>';
            //echo array_search("DATE AMOUNT", $currentArray);
            //echo '</pre>';

        }    
    }        
    closedir($handle);        
}

//subtract two because the folders "array" and "converted" are included because PHP does not differentiate
//between folders and files
$nodeCount = $nodeCount - 2; 

echo "<br />";
echo "I counted $nodeCount pdf files";
echo "<br />";

//open the directory
if ($handle2 = opendir('/var/www/html/pay.mistequaygroup.com/upload/converted')) 
{
    //check to see if we have reached the last file of our directory, if not stay in loop
    while (false !== ($currentText = readdir($handle2))) 
    {
        //filter out files named . and ..
       if ($currentText != "." && $currentText != "..") 
       {
               //Create a file for array to be printed to
               $createArray = fopen("/var/www/html/pay.mistequaygroup.com/upload/arrays/" . $currentText . ".txt", "w+") or die ("Cannot find file to create array, ID 2");


               //read the file we are on from the loop into the array 
               $currentArray = file("/var/www/html/pay.mistequaygroup.com/upload/converted/" . $currentText, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES) or die ("Cannot find file to create array, ID 1");

               //$countArray = array_search(". . . . . . . . . .", $currentArray);

               //echo $countArray;

               //print array to .txt file for debugging purposes
               $out = print_r($currentArray, true);
               fwrite($createArray, $out);
               fclose($createArray);


               //Loop?
            array_search($empID, $currentArray);

            //need to loop through the array we are on, looking for numbers that match the employee ID's 
            //OR we might have to search for names within a string of text and then get the corresponding ID for that user from the database? 

            //brainstorming 
               $query = SELECT * FROM `profile_values` WHERE `fid` = 2 AND `value` = $employeeID; 



               //DOES NOT WORK AS EXPECTED
               $indexEmpid = 0;
               foreach ($currentArray as $value)
               {
                   //set the value to 28 and it doubles each time the loop runs so there is no need to add 28 each time
                   //every 28th index in our array is an employee id
                   $indexEmpid = $indexEmpid + 28;
                   $currentEmployeeID = $currentArray[$indexEmpid];
                   echo "<br />";
                   echo "Employee ID's found: $currentEmployeeID";
                //echo "Employee ID's found: $currentArray[$indexEmpid]";
                echo "<br />";
                echo "IndexEmpid: $indexEmpid";            
               }




       }
     }

}


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it using the SQL `IN` clause as:

```
$empIDs = array(1,2,3);
$query = "SELECT name FROM emp WHERE ID IN (" . implode(',',$empIDs) . ")";
```

Comment: Sorry, I was not being clear enough. Whats really going on here is that I am trying to import paystubs. I do this by converting a PDF file to txt then read the txt file into an array in PHP. I can't just go every 28th line for example and get the employee ID because the ID's are not every 28th index in the array. So I figured the next best way is to search for the ID's. I have a drupal database any every username has an employee ID associated with it. Im looking to search my array that is the paystub for a matching employee ID from my database. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

use : `where employeeID in (id list......)` (separated by comma)

more in : [Passing an array to a query using a WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/php-mysql-using-an-array-in-where-clause)