# WHERE IN SQL condition problem

Tags: php, sql

I have this query:

```
"SELECT * FROM informations WHERE ". $id ." IN (ids)"
```

It only works if $id is the first value from ids... in ids values are "1,2,3,4,5".

Is there a way for it to work with the rest of the ids?

Comment: It would be nice to get some feedback from George on all these suggestions he's getting.

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/php-mysql-using-an-array-in-where-clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `ids` is a field containing comma-delimited values, then your query is like:

```
SELECT * FROM `informations` WHERE 3 IN ("1,2,3,4,5")
```

Instead of what it should be:

```
SELECT * FROM `informations` WHERE 3 IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

There is no automatic tokenisation (splitting on `,`) performed; the one value of `ids` is not automatically converted into a list for you such that `IN` can work.

Unfortunately your table design has been your undoing here. Can you split the IDs into a separate table using the principle of *database normalisation*?

Then your query might look like:

```
SELECT * FROM `informations` WHERE 3 IN (
   SELECT `id`
     FROM `ids`
    WHERE `informations`.`id` = `ids`.`information_id`
)
```

BTW, "information" is a non-countable noun and, as such, "informations" is wrong.

---

**Update** (thanks for the idea, a1ex07!)

Although this is hackery and I still suggest fixing your table layout, I'll be kind and suggest a quick fix.

Willempie was close with:

```
$query = 'SELECT *
            FROM `informations`
           WHERE `ids` LIKE "%' . $id . '%"';
```

Unfortunately, a wildcard match isn't quite powerful enough. Consider if `ids` is like `"1,6,9,12,35,4"` and `$id` is like `3`. You get a false positive. The `LIKE` statement needs to be aware of the commas.

You can add multiple cases:

```
$query = 'SELECT *
            FROM `informations`
           WHERE `ids` LIKE "%,' . $id . ',%"
              OR `ids` LIKE "%,' . $id . '"
              OR `ids` LIKE "' . $id . ',%"';
```

Or, for brevity, you can work around this with [regular expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp):

```
$query = 'SELECT *
            FROM `informations`
           WHERE `ids` REGEXP "(^|,)' . $id . '(,|$)"';
```

For any `$id` you wish to find, before it must be the start of `ids` (`^`) or a comma; after it must be a comma or the end of `ids` (`$`). This ensures that `$id` must be found as a *whole, comma-delimited token*.

It's a little like "Whole Word Only" in word processor searches, but with commas separating "words" instead of spaces.

---

**Update 2**

Another way uses [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), which performs a search within a comma-delimited string:

```
$query = 'SELECT *
            FROM `informations`
           WHERE FIND_IN_SET("' . $id . '", `ids`)';
```

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

```
"SELECT *
 FROM Informations
 WHERE ids LIKE \"" . $id . ", %\" -- try to match against the first value in ids
 OR ids LIKE \"%," . $id . ",%\" -- try to match against a value in ids that is neither the first nor the last value
 OR ids LIKE \"%," .$id . "\"  -- try to match against the last value found in ids"
```

Comment: This is good, except it breaks if `ids` is like `"1,6,9,12,35,4"` and `$id` is `3`.

Comment: Good point, you can expand the WHERE clause to include the ',' in the LIKE statement. It would be .. LIKE \"%," . $id . ",%\"

Comment: Then what if the `$id` is at the start of `ids`? Unfortunately, `LIKE` is not powerful to search an expression in this way.

Comment: Aside from a minor typo on the last line, yea! :) Add a bit of explanation as to why the OP's original approach didn't work, and I'll vote you up.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is technically correct but the values for 'ids' are not.

You should enclose the values of ids within single quotes. If I were to write the code without using ids, it would be like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM informations WHERE ". $id ." IN ('1','2','3','4','5')"
```

More info on this rule here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

Comment: You're assuming his ids are strings?

Comment: This is completely unhelpful, because he _is_ using `ids`.

Comment: No need to be rude. This still does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. If `ids` is a column in `informations` your code is just a weird way to express `"SELECT * FROM informations WHERE ids = ". $id "`; If it is a string, I don't see why you need `WHERE` at all : expression `$id in (1,2,3,4,5)` is constant, it doesn't require interaction with database; in any case you either grab all rows from `informations` or none.

**UPDATE**
Another suggestion :maybe `ids` is a string field in `informations` that contains "1,2,3,4,5". In this case you cannot get expected results by using `WHERE ... IN`. You need to use [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) to check if string contains your number.

Answer (score -1):

It has to be column name then IN (comma separated values here).

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name IN (value1,value2,...)
```

Answer (score -2):

You did an error in sql syntax.

This is the correct syntax

```
"SELECT * FROM informations WHERE ids IN (". $id .")";
```