# How to remove last comma (,) from array?

Tags: php

I've gone through this address:

[Passing an array to a query using a WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/php-mysql-using-an-array-in-where-clause)

and found that if I use a join clause to separate values `,` is also at the end of the array. How can I remove last?

I am using like this

```
$ttst=array();
$ttst=array(); 
$tt = "SELECT frd_id FROM network WHERE mem_id='$userId'"; 
$appLdone = execute_query($tt, true, "select"); 
foreach($appLdone as $kk=>$applist){ 
    $ttst[] = $applist['frd_id']; 
} 
$result = implode(',', $ttst);
```

then also coming last ,

Thanks.

---

but it doesn't give single quote to each value .

Comment: you use join() to separate values?  You mean split() right?

Comment: @Cold Hawaiian,                                                     $ids = join(',',$galleries);  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM galleries WHERE id IN ($ids)";

Comment: So you have an empty element in the array?

Comment: If adding rtrim like in my answer doesn't give the result you want, you should echo or var_dump $result and explain how it SHOULD look, to clarify the question.

Answer (score 10):

```
join(',', array_filter($galleries))
```

`array_filter` gets rid of empty elements that you seem to have. Of course, you should take care not to have empty elements in there in the first place.

Answer (score 9):

You could use [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) (or [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)):

```
$myStr = 'planes,trains,automobiles,';
$myStr = trim($myStr, ',');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$str = "orange,banana,apple,";
$str = rtrim($str,',');
```

This will result in

```
$str = "orange,banana,apple";
```

#### Update

Based on your situation:

```
$result = implode(',', $ttst);
$result = rtrim($result,',');
```

Comment: Warning: substr() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(...); 
$last = end($arr); 
unset($last);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the trailing "," is an array element of itself, use [array_pop()](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php), else, use [rtrim()](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

```
$array = array('one','two',3,',');
array_pop($array);
print_r($array);
```

Gives:

> Array ( [0] => one [1](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) => two [2](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) => 3
>   )

Answer (score 0):

No need for length. Just take from beginning to the (last character - 1)

```
$finalResult = $str = substr($result, 0, -1);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use implode() instead! See Example #1 here http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Edit:

I think a quick fix would be (broken down in steps):

```
$temp = rtrim(implode(',', $ttst), ','); //trim last comma caused by last empty value
$temp2 = "'"; //starting quote
$temp2 .=  str_replace(",", "','", $temp); //quotes around commas
$temp2 .= "'"; //ending quote
$result = $temp2; // = 'apples','bananas','oranges'
```

This should give you single-quote around the strings, but **note** that if some more values in the array are sometimes empty you will probably have to write a `foreach` loop and build the string.

Comment: i am using like this  $ttst=array();$ttst=array();
        $tt = "SELECT frd_id FROM network WHERE mem_id='$userId'";
        $appLdone = execute_query($tt, true, "select");
foreach($appLdone as $kk=>$applist){

            $ttst[] = $applist['frd_id'];
        }
        $result = implode(',', $ttst);  then also coming last ,

Comment: @RockDance, you should add that code (properly formatted) to the question.

Comment: @deceze, ok, I've always used implode and never join, and knew that implode only puts commas *between* the items. It's apparent now that he has 1 (or more) empty string results in the array, but it was hard to make that out before he edited the question.