# How to remove comma from this json object?

Tags: php, json

I have a search query as

```
$sql="SELECT user_id,user_name,user_occupation FROM profile WHERE user_email LIKE '%peace%'";

$result=mysql_query($sql);
$jsonResult = '{"results" : [ ';
while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$jsonResult .=json_encode($data).',';
}
$jsonResult .= ']}';

echo $jsonResult;
```

After referring [How to remove last comma (,) from array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368075/how-to-remove-last-comma-from-array) , i added

```
$sql="SELECT user_id,user_name,user_occupation FROM profile WHERE user_email LIKE '%peace%'";

$result=mysql_query($sql);
$jsonResult = '{"results" : [ ';
while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$jsonResult .=json_encode($data).',';
}
$jsonResult .= ']}';

$finalResult = rtrim(',',$jsonResult);
echo $finalResult;
```

This gives me an output as ...

```
{"results" : [ {"user_id":"2","user_name":"peace","user_occupation":"Web Developer"},  
               {"user_id":"3","user_name":"lover","user_occupation":"Web Developer"}
               {"user_id":"4","user_name":"User4","user_occupation":"Developer"},
               {"user_id":"5","user_name":"User5","user_occupation":"Developer"},]}
```

I want to remove the last comma from the results array

Comment: When you iterate over your results, instead of appending to a JSON string, add the results to an array.  Then when you are done iterating, convert that array to json via `json_encode`.  You avoid any JSON syntax issues this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this

```
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$jsonResult = '{"results" : [ ';
$i=0;
while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   if($i != 0){
       $jsonResult .=',';
   }
   $jsonResult .=json_encode($data);
   i++;
}
$jsonResult .= ']}';
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of building a string within the loop, populate an array instead, with each element being a single associative array (row) from your result set. Then, after the loop, simply json_encode the array you've built.

Comment: ...and blast if cheeken didn't manage to type that faster than I did. :)

Comment: No worries, it looks like you won the race!  :)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. But i found @selvakumar answer helpful. Eventhough u remind me with the best logic...

Answer (score 1):

[`rtrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) removes characters from the end of the string. As you've added `]}`, the comma is no longer at the end.

Trim the comma before adding the last part:

```
$finalResult = rtrim(',',$jsonResult);
$finalResult .= ']}';
```

Although, as Christopher says, it's not a very good idea to build a JSON string manually.

Answer (score 0):

can u try like filling some array from the incoming result and then just json encode that array like

```
..push result row arrays to $result ..
$data = array('results' => $results);
json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="SELECT user_id,user_name,user_occupation FROM profile WHERE user_email LIKE '%peace%'";

$result=mysql_query($sql);
$jsonResult = '{"results" : [ ';
$counter = 1;
while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
if($counter!=1)
 {
 $jsonResult .= ','.json_encode($data);
 }
else
 {
 $jsonResult .=json_encode($data);
 }
$counter++;
}
$jsonResult .= ']}';
$finalResult = rtrim(',',$jsonResult);
echo $finalResult;
```

Answer (score 0):

Push your INNER array into another array like this:

```
...
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$final_result=json_encode(['result' => $result]);
```

All done. Have fun!