# save array with commas in ternary condition php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array

```
$this->input->post("first_array")={ one two three }
```

I need to create an array which will hold several arrays like that

so I am doing a 'fisrt_array' to hold the array, first verifiying that it is indeed an array, then if it is not set I put a 'not defined' string

```
array(
'fisrt_array' => is_array($this->input->post("first_array")) ? implode(' ',$this->input->post("first_array"))   : 'Not defined'
);
```

So if it is set, I implode the array that is saved in $this->input->post("first_array")

All is correct but I store the result like **one two three**  instead of **one,two,three**

How can i save the array in that format?

If i do `implode(',',$this->input->post("first_array")` i would store **one,two,three,** with last not wanted comma..

Comment: `$this->input->post("first_array")={ one two three }` this code will produce an error, please show us all the relevant lines!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove last comma (,) from array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368075/how-to-remove-last-comma-from-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`implode(',',$this->input->post("first_array")` should not add a comma after the last element.

This should work for you. Having said that, you're declaring your array in a weird way.

Use `$this->input->post['First_Array'] = array('One', 'Two', 'Three');`

Edit: Also, just re-read the OP. If you just want to add your arrays to another array (in PHP, we refer to arrays of arrays as 'multidimensional arrays), just do:

`second_array[] = $this->input->post['First_Array'];`