# MySQL SELECT query IN PHP Array

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a PHP array and what I am trying to do is use that in my MySQL query to select only the ones that are in the array.

I have this:

```
SELECT * FROM table IN ('.implode(',', $array).')
```

I guess what needs to happen is I need quotes around each array item for this to work.  Right now it just has **one, two, three, four**  where it should be **"one", "two", "three", "four"**

How could I do that?  Or is there another way to do what I am looking for?

Thanks!

Comment: check this link you can find your answer
 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/php-mysql-using-an-array-in-where-clause][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/php-mysql-using-an-array-in-where-clause

Comment: I hope you've remembered to pass the strings in your array through [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql-real-escape-string) first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would do it,

```
"'" . implode("','", $array) . "'"
```