# MySQL query: update for set of keys

Tags: mysql, set

I know I've seen this syntax before, but I can't remember it/find it on here.

I want to write the condensed form of the following query:

```
UPDATE Users SET Activated = 1 WHERE ID = 1 OR ID = 2 OR ID = 3 OR ID = 4 OR...
```

There is a way to have the `WHERE` attribute be a set of values, something like:

```
UPDATE Users SET Activated = 1 WHERE ID IN_ARRAY(1, 2, 3, 4, ...)
```

Can anyone tell me the exact syntax?

Thank you!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/php-mysql-using-an-array-in-where-clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the keyword is `IN`:

```
UPDATE Users SET Activated = 1 WHERE ID IN (1, 2, 3, 4,...)
                                        ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Just lose the IN_ARRAY string and it will function