# How to represent a PHP array as a comma-delimited string?

Tags: php, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP/MYSQL using an array in WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/php-mysql-using-an-array-in-where-clause)

I have an array with ID values [1,5,2,6,7...] and I need to use that in a MySQL item_id IN (1,5,2,6,7...) statement to select only rows with an ID listed in the array. How can I go about converting the $arrIDs to something that I can insert into my SQL query?

EDIT- context of the call:

```
if(!IsNullOrEmptyString($_GET["view_playlist"])) {
        session_destroy();
    }
    $id_list = implode(",", $_SESSION("playlist"));
    $sql = 'SELECT t.track_id, t.track_title, t.track_num, al.album_title, g.genre_name, a.artist_name, t.length, t.track_rating '.
    'FROM track t, genre g, artist a, album al '.
    'WHERE t.track_id IN('.$id_list.' AND t.genre = g.genre_id AND t.artist = a.artist_id AND t.album = al.album_id';
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`implode()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php);

```
$ids = implode(',', $your_array);
```

Comment: I get an error - PHP Fatal error: Function name must be a string

Comment: Check right before this line of code for an error. This little snippet is correct.

Comment: I have edited the question - the error occurs on the line where implode is called.

Comment: Who voted this down? And why?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [PDO](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (which you should, as the `mysql_` functions are antiquated and should be abandoned), then you'll want to construct a parameterized query using the number of elements in your array to match the number of `?`'s in your SQL.

Here's an example in PDO:

```
$ids = array(1, 2, 3, 4);

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydbname", 'username', 'password');
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}

$inClause = trim(str_repeat('?, ', count($ids)), ', ');
$stm = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN ('.$inClause.')');
$stm->execute($ids);

// resulting SQL: SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id IN (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: I am using mysqli, and why do you think they are antiquated? They work great, never really had any issues?

Comment: @antonpug: Did you really downvote me because **you** misread my answer? I never said not to use `mysqli` functions. I said the `mysql_` functions are antiquated and should be abandoned, not `mysqli`. This answer shows the proper way to do this using parameterized queries (which is the *preferred* way to use non-literal data in SQL).