# Multiple WHERE AND Querys - Mysql / PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to get the results of one query into the `WHERE` statement of another:

```
$query1 = "SELECT DISTINCT company_id FROM location WHERE state = 'XX'";
$result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
    //Collect WHERE STATEMENT HERE
}
```

I've tried the following:

```
$q1 = "SELECT company FROM company WHERE id = '16', id = '7' ORDER BY company";
$q1 = "SELECT company FROM company WHERE id = '16' AND id = '7' ORDER BY company";
$q1 = "SELECT company FROM company WHERE id = '16' && id = '7' ORDER BY company";
```

Along with other variations

Googling has only provided multiple `WHERE AND` if using different table names, but not the same.  Anyone have any pointers?

Comment: the field 'id' cannot be 16 AND 7 at the same time. Use "or"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for a generalized code :

```
$ids = array (
[0] => 2
[1] => 4
[2] => 19
[3] => 16
);  

$ids = join(',',$ids);  
$sql = "SELECT * FROM company WHERE id IN ($ids)";
```

reffer : [same example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/php-mysql-using-an-array-in-where-clause)

Comment: I've had the best luck with this one, but for whatever reason, I am only getting 1 result (`$query = "SELECT DISTINCT company_id FROM location WHERE state = 'XX'";)` in the array when numrows tells me there should be 23.  Doing `print_r (mysql_fetch_array($result));` Only shows 1 result as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `IN`:

```
$x = array('16', '7');

$q1 = "SELECT company FROM company WHERE id IN(". implode(',', $x) .") ORDER BY company";
```

Answer (score 0):

use `OR`

```
$q1 = "SELECT company FROM company WHERE (id = '16' OR id = '7') ORDER BY company";
```