# Normalizing CSV data with multiple entities

Tags: sql

I'm importing a CSV into a database that contains multiple entities: `City`, `State`, and `Country`.

I'd like to have a hierarchy of references using foreign keys across the tables:

- `City.State_Ref` -> `State.ID`
- `State.Country_Ref` -> `Country.ID`

So the `City` table will have the following schema in the end:

```
CREATE TABLE "City" (
  "ID" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
  "Name" INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "State_Ref" INTEGER,
  FOREIGN KEY("State_Ref") REFERENCES "State"("ID")
)
```

Setting up the `State` and `Country` tables is easy enough, but when there is the same `State` name that occurs in different `Country` records, I'm unable to pick the correct one:

```
UPDATE City SET State_Ref = (SELECT ID from State WHERE City.State = State.Name);
```

This will match multiple records and `LIMIT` just grabs the first one (which isn't always right).

I have also tried `JOIN` to create a new table with the correct references:

```
SELECT City.Name as Name, State.ID as State_Ref

FROM City
    INNER JOIN State ON City.State = State.Name
    INNER JOIN Country ON City.Country = Country.Name

ORDER BY City.Name ASC;
```

But this results in multiple records for all of the `State` duplicates.

Sample data (the problem happens with "Wonderland" since "Colorado" exists in multiple countries):

```
Country         State         Name
United States   New York      Kingston  
United States   Texas         Paris 
England         Kent          Kingston  
United States   Maine         Paris 
France          Île-de-France Paris 
United States   Colorado      Denver    
Canada          Colorado      Wonderland
```

Any pointers for setting `State_Ref` properly would be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't think I would bother normalizing the data, unless you have a specific reason -- outside this data -- to reference `country` and `state` entities.

Comment: Yeah...  This is a sample for a much larger set of data.  The "State" and "Country" equivalents each have additional data associated with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131496/how-to-do-join-on-multiple-criteria-returning-all-combinations-of-both-criteria), I was able to figure it out...  I wasn't filtering for the matching `Country` in the second `JOIN`.

```
SELECT
    City.Name as Name, State.ID as State_Ref

FROM City
    INNER JOIN State ON City.State = State.Name
    INNER JOIN Country ON (State.Country_Ref = Country.ID AND City.Country = Country.Name)

ORDER BY City.Name ASC;
```