# Using PHP Join on a multidimensional array to combine values

Tags: php, join, multidimensional-array

Should be a nice easy one today but I can't find the answer anywhere.

I have a multidimensional array. It stores partid and quantity.

```
$pCombined[] = array ( $newName[$b], $newQty[$b] );
```

I want to use PHP join as suggested here: [Passing an array to a query using a WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/php-mysql-using-an-array-in-where-clause)

I need to get more data from mySQL about the parts so I need the list of ids joined up as I don't like the idea of running one SQL query for each row.

I tried to use:

```
$ids = join(',', $pCombined);
```

That just gives array, array, array....e.t.c.

I tried a few obvious combinations of square brackets. What I guess I want is...

```
$ids = join(',', $pCombined[*][0]); (where * is all)
```

I think I might also be overcomplicating the whole thing and I could use foreach or a for loop and join manually I guess. Its not quite a basic shopping cart but the principals are similar. Any ideas how I can do this or perhaps push me in a different direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

to combine array elements can use the following

$elemens = array("one","two","there","four")

$exit = implode(',',$elements);

print_r($exit);//one,two,...

I hope you serve

Comment: I don't think this is really what I am after. I need to prepare them for SQL but the original array is multi-dimensional. Imagine $pCombined[x][y] where [x] is rows and [y] is columns. I need to join all the items in column 1.

Comment: Thanks for the use of implode though. I used a for loop to collect the column data into a new array and then used $ids = implode(',', $newArray);
I'm convinced there must be a way to do this without using a loop to extract the data I want from the multidimensional array though.