# SQL SELECT multiple authors?

Tags: sql, wordpress, archive

How do I select multiple items in my search? Here I have a list of authors that I'd like to get the categories from... but it doesn't work with commas. What do I need to do?

```
<?php   
$author = "4,1,909,900,970,968,5,972,969,965,971";

$categories = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT DISTINCT(terms.term_id) as ID, terms.name, terms.slug, tax.description
FROM $wpdb->posts as posts
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships as relationships ON posts.ID = relationships.object_ID
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy as tax ON relationships.term_taxonomy_id = tax.term_taxonomy_id
LEFT JOIN $wpdb->terms as terms ON tax.term_id = terms.term_id
WHERE posts.post_status = 'publish' AND
    posts.post_author = '$author' AND
    tax.taxonomy = 'category'
ORDER BY terms.name ASC
");

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Take a Look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/php-mysql-using-an-array-in-where-clause)**

basically you're going to need:

```
WHERE posts.post_author IN ($author)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm quite new to SQL-ing, so it's very nice to have someone pass these annoying beginners bumps that takes up so much unnecessary time.

Comment: @2famous.TV if you find this answered as solved your problem then accept it

Comment: Ahh... cool! I'm new to this, and was puzzled that I'm not allowed to vote up and down. Accepting is pretty cool too :)