# Match the exact substring after split in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Hi i am using codeigniter and in database my table name is posts have one column countriesId in which i have values like this`1, 21, 13, 162, 172, 182, 155`.

so in query i want to split the values `1, 21, 13...` and match the query value.

for example if i use LIKE and i am asking about record of countryID `"1"` it will match `1, 21, 13` because there is "1" in values. how can i break the string within query and match the exact integer?

Thanks..

Comment: try `where column in()`

Comment: check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/php-mysql-using-an-array-in-where-clause

Comment: @krishna read the question again, please

Answer (score 0):

You can [**FIND_IN_SET()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to use the FIND_IN_SET function.  I don't know what your database schema looks like but your query will look something like this.

```
SELECT countries.*, posts.countriesId FROM posts, countries WHERE FIND_IN_SET(countries.countryID, posts.countriesId) AND posts.postId = '1'
```