# How to search a database with an array

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I want to search the row(venue_id) of a database with an array ($valueIDArray).

Is this the right way to do this?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM venue_booking
WHERE venue_id = $valueIDArray";
```

Comment: If venue (from your other question) and venue_booking are two tables in the same database you are much better off combining them into one query with a join, and avoiding any extra work for you the programmer, and for the php and sql servers too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `$valueIDArray` values are numeric, `implode` into a comma separated list and use the `IN` clause:

```
$values = implode(',', $valueIDArray);
$query  = "SELECT * FROM venue_booking WHERE venue_id IN ($values)";
```

If text etc. you need quotes:

```
$values = "'". implode("','", $valueIDArray) ."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is vulnerable to something called SQL injection; you generally prevent these attacks by using [prepared statements](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

If you mean, "Is this SQL statement syntactically valid?" yes, but not for an array. You need to use the IN statement; see [Passing an array to a query using a WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/php-mysql-using-an-array-in-where-clause).

Comment: This is only for coursework, and we have been told that wont be taken into consideration

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM venue_booking
          WHERE venue_id IN (" . implode(", ", $valueIDArray) . ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

First make a comma separated list of IDs and then use IN clause of SQL.

$comma_separated = implode(",", $valueIDArray);

$query = "SELECT * FROM venue_booking
WHERE venue_id in ($comma_separated)";