# how to use a php array variable as column name in mysql select statement

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to use the following select query in my php code where all var1,var2,var3,var4,var5 are array variables but its not working

```
 $sql="SELECT SNo,Date,FROM_TIME,TO_TIME,$var1,$var2,$var3,$var4,$var5 
 FROM $table_name 
 WHERE Date='$start_date'";
```

Comment: Define "not working". Also, why? There's a reason prepared queries (which you should be using, hint hint!) don't let you do this.

Comment: tell us the (mysql?) error

Comment: "Array variables"? Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/php-mysql-using-an-array-in-where-clause

Comment: is there one array, so you should use `$var[0], $var[1], $var[2], ...` or are there more arrays, e.g. `$var1[0], $var2[0], $var3[0], ...` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can build your mysql select query using array value by this way

```
<?php 
$columnArray=array('column1'=>'value1',
        'column2'=>'value2', 
        'column3'=>'value3',
        'column4'=>'value4');
        //print_r($columns);
         $columns = implode(',',array_keys($columnArray));
        if(count($columnArray)>0)
         $comma=',';
        else 
          $comma='';

       $sql="SELECT SNo,Date,FROM_TIME,TO_TIME" .$comma." $columns
          FROM tableName
          WHERE Date='2014-06-22'";
        print $sql; //final query
        ?>
```

Comment: You can simplify this a bit and don't specify keys ('column1', 'column2', ...) in array because `join` will join values not keys anyway. Also there is comma after $columns in SQL making it not valid. And one more thing - if $columnArray will be empty, then you don't need comma after TO_TIME too.