# how to SELECT mysql using array in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have an array in databae like this :

```
    Field : smt_id
    Value in database : 261, 323
    type : varchar(100)
```

**smt_id is not fix field.** if i updated as 3 arrays it will be like this example : 261, 323, 111 and variable $mid will change to 261, 323, 111

now i want to do sql statement like this using this variable.

$mid = 261, 323

```
$sql = "SELECT first_name FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."members WHERE member_id ='$mid'";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$db);
```

when i print the sql the result is like this:

```
SELECT first_name FROM AT_members WHERE member_id ='261, 323'
```

My question is, how i change above sql so it become like this :

```
SELECT first_name FROM AT_members WHERE member_id IN ('261', '323')
```

and how can i make every result break like this:

```
John 
Merry
```

Comment: Always just 2 values separated by a comma? varchar data type?

Comment: no i inserted the database as an array so it can be updated more than two

Comment: what is the data type of the column smt_id?

Comment: Assuming this `$mid = 261, 323` is your actual code, you'd need to do `$mid = array('261', '323');` and then explode on the array. That may also be implode or even `in_array()`. There are a many ways of doing this, but you get the general idea ;)

Comment: yup, creating a string with desired separator from an array is implode

Comment: @epipav Depends on the function used. As I said, there are multiple ways of doing this. It's a bit unclear though as to how OP is iterating over the variable/numbers.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i just want to change 123, 234 to "123", "234" so  my sql works.. you know how?

Comment: Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?lq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP/MYSQL using an array in WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/php-mysql-using-an-array-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$mid = explode(',', preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $mid));
$sql = 'SELECT first_name FROM '.TABLE_PREFIX.'members WHERE member_id IN ('.implode(',', $mid).')';
```

Comment: This is the best approach for the current case, as $mid is normalized in a separate step before being provided to the SQL query. But $mid should be an array beforehand, not at this last moment ;)

Answer (score 0):

Asserting `$mid` is an array:

```
'WHERE member_id IN ('.implode(',', $mid).')'
```

It also works if the array has only one value.

Just as a reminder, code like that is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: hi thanks. your code ok but no row return.. MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)

Comment: because your variable $mid is not an array most likely

Comment: If $mid is a string like `'261, 323'` you are doing something wrong.

Comment: hurmm.. maybe.. because when i echo it will be ex: 123, 234 ... HOW CAN I CHANGE '261, 323' <-- VARCHAR to ('261', '323') ... do you know how?

Comment: Don't confuse PHP types and MySQL types. There are 2 separate worlds. Then, you rather should use [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) for debugging. Here you'll likely see your variable is a string. So just put it like so: `'WHERE IN ('.$mid.')'`. But this is dirty, $mid should be an array, consider reviewing your preceding code.

Answer (score 0):

### stop using mysql extension

it is deprecated. use mysqli or PDO instead(**sql injection alert**). Moreover don't push your variables directly to the query, use prepared statements. Check [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).
Imploding is well explained in Double Gras' answer. For your second question, if you want every result one by one, you should fetch them one by one. fetch_assoc is good here for mysqli extension.

simple usage of fetch_assoc:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

        /* fetch associative array */
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["column1"], $row["column2"]);
        }
```

Comment: Indeed, running the query (which is done on the SQL server) then fetching the results (at the pace you want, consumes network traffic) are 2 distinct operations.

Comment: While I agree with the sentiments, this answer does *not* answer the OPs question - nor does it show proper multi-parameter binding. If an *actual* answer is not provided, consider a comment.

Comment: _and how can i make every result break like this:_