# Explode php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have following array result :

```
Array ( [0] => company_1 [1] => company_10 [2] => company_15 )
```

I want the result something like this as i can use in the `mysql IN` query clause:

```
$result= "1, 10, 15";
```

I use explode function but again it is returning both array values separately like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => company [1] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => company [1] => 10 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => company [1] => 15 ) )
```

But wondering how can i only get numbers separately and stored in one string.

Any help ?
'

Comment: why do you explode an array to make a string? surely you want to implode?

Comment: @andrew: yes. but first i have to use explode as i can separate the number from company.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/php-mysql-using-an-array-in-where-clause

Comment: Come on guys, where's the map / reduce answer ;)

Comment: oh,ok. I see what you're trying to do now, sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your initial data is an array, just explode them again each them gather them inside then finally use implode. Example:

```
$result = array('company_1', 'company_10', 'company_15');
$result = array_map(function($piece){
    return explode('_', $piece)[1]; // note: for php 5.4 or greater
    // return str_replace('company_', '', $piece);
}, $result);
$result = implode(', ', $result);
echo $result; // 1, 10, 15
```

Comment: if `company_` is constant, dagons solution is probably for the best

Answer (score 1):

You have to pick the second part after you explode.

```
$result = array_map(function ($val) {
  $tmp = explode('_', $val);
  return isset($tmp[1]) ? $tmp[1] : null;
}, $array);

$result = implode(',', $result); // "1,10,5"
```

Comment: I think you want `_`, not `-`

Comment: str_replace() is probably quicker if "company_" never changes

Comment: @Dagon's right. A simple `implode` and `str_replace` would be faster and simpler

Comment: I want that first sentence framed for my office.