# PHP MYSQL String ERROR

Tags: php, mysql, string

how do i convert a string like this:

```
"joe,anna,kwame,kofi"
```

to:

```
"joe","anna","kwame","kofi"
```

I am trying to use this in an sql statement with an IN clause but i keep getting the error as shown below:

Last SQL query failed:

```
SELECT * FROM view_salesreport WHERE deleted =0 AND saletype IN (dropoff,pickup)
```

Can anyone help

Comment: How are you getting that string in the first place?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP/MYSQL using an array in WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/php-mysql-using-an-array-in-where-clause)

Comment: Don't try to do it in SQL - do it in your PHP.  OR,GIYF  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x   http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/19/how-to-split-a-string-by-delimited-char-in-sql-server/   http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings   https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/T-SQL-Script-to-Split-a-308206f3  etc etc etc

Answer (score 1):

```
// split string into array based on commas
// result: array("joe","anna","kwame","kofi")
$arr = explode(",","joe,anna,kwame,kofi");

// create a string with a "?" for each item in the array
// result: ?, ?, ?, ?
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($arr) - 1) . '?';

// insert $in in SQL query
// result: SELECT * FROM view_salesreport WHERE deleted = 0 AND saletype IN (?, ?, ?, ?)
$sql = "SELECT * FROM view_salesreport WHERE deleted = 0 AND saletype IN ($in)";

// prepares a statement for execution
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);

// executes a prepared statement with array of parameters
$stm->execute($arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this:

```
 $string = "joe,anna,kwame,kofi";
 $string = str_replace("'","\\'",$string);
 $string = "'".str_replace(',',"','",$string)."'";
```

Comment: It produces: `'joe'anna'kwame'kofi'`

Comment: Now try with this: $string = "joe,anna,kwame,kofi,o'brian";

Comment: Yes, it still is a problem. Try this: `$string = "joe,anna,kwame,kofi,o\\'brian";`. And even after you quote the backslash, there still is a possibility to produce invalid SQL using this code. For proper quoting use [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or, even better, use prepared statements (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27783508/4265352))

Answer (score -1):

http://php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php

try something like this:

```
$output = ''
foreach (explode(',' , $yourString) as $name) {
  $output . = $name
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can easily use `explode()` and `implode()` to get the string format you want.  For example:

```
$initial_string = "joe,anna,kwame,kofi";
// split string into array based on commas
$names = explode(',', $initial_string);
// combine back into string using implode
$query = "SELECT * FROM view_salesreport WHERE deleted =0 AND saletype IN ('" . implode("','", $names) .  "')";
```

Comment: Try with this: `$initial_string = "joe,anna,kwame,kofi,o'brian";`