# Cannot fetch all mysqli results $id to 2nd query

Tags: php

I cannot get all user id with 1st query to use these ids to 2nd query.

When I count 1st query its show 1 always. That means it get only one result from sql. But I want, Use my 1st query's all id to 2nd query.

Please where is my wrong here?

My code:

```
$a = $session->username;
$b = $session->pname;
if (empty($b)) $b = $a;
$g = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT id FROM update WHERE `from_id`='$b' OR `to_id`='".$session->bdid."'") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($g)) {
$id = $row['id'];
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka');
$timestamp = date("M j, y; g:i a", time() - 2592000);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($g);

$u = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM update WHERE `id`='".$id."' AND `view` = '0' AND `created` > '".$timestamp."' ORDER BY created DESC") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
$count1 = mysqli_num_rows($u);

$count2 = ($count - $count1);

echo ''.$count2.'';
}
```

Comment: where is the end of the while block?

Comment: Try calling enumeration method outside while cycle. And why don't you use OOP syntax for mysqli?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysqli_fetch_assoc returns only one row at a time, it is standard behavior
so first you should get all data into you arrays

```
$a = $session->username;
$b = $session->pname;
if (empty($b)) $b = $a;
$g = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT id FROM update WHERE `from_id`='$b' OR `to_id`='".$session->bdid."'") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
$ids=[];//init ids as empty array
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($g)) {
$ids[] = $row['id'];
}
```

And now all ids you need are in $ids array, so you can use them:

```
$timestamp = date("M j, y; g:i a", time() - 2592000);
foreach( $ids as $id ) {
   $u = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM update WHERE `id`='".$id."' AND `view` = '0' AND `created` > '".$timestamp."' ORDER BY created DESC") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
  ///some code here////
  }
```

**UPD**
To use all ids in ONE query, change second part into this:

```
$timestamp = date("M j, y; g:i a", time() - 2592000);
$u = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM update WHERE `id` IN( ".join(",",$ids).") AND `view` = '0' AND `created` > '".$timestamp."' ORDER BY created DESC") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));
  ///some code here////
```

Comment: If I echo ''.$count1.''; its display also 1 and if I echo ''.$id.''; its show only one id. But with my previous above code if echo ''.$id.''; its display all id but in case echo ''.$count1.''; display 1.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should declare your SQL statement more accurately.

```
$sql = "SELECT `id` FROM `update` WHERE `from_id`='".$b."' OR `to_id`='".$session->bdid."'";
```

Furthermore in your while loop you will only fetch a single ID at a time, which means you have to define an array like:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($g)) {
  $id[] = $row['id'];
}
```

After this you can use your ID array for your 2nd SQL statement, using the **IN()** operator (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/php-mysql-using-an-array-in-where-clause) post for further reading). Be aware your code is very vulnerable in terms od Sql injections!

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `update` WHERE `id` IN (".$id.") AND `view` = '0' AND `created` > '".$timestamp."' ORDER BY `created` DESC"
```