# Convert an array into format for an WHERE IN mysql clause

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string

I have an array that contains **strings**

e.g array('14183f6c-9bf5', '074306fb-6eaf')

I want to convert this into a format readable for an mysql query with an IN statement but I keep getting issues as its a string..

Essentially get this to be formatted as such in my sql query - I am using implode but to no avail.. any ideas

Guid IN ("14183f6c-9bf5", "074306fb-6eaf")

```
$Guids = array('14183f6c-9bf5', '074306fb-6eaf');
$csv = implode('",', $Guids);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/php-mysql-using-an-array-in-where-clause?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$whereIn = implode('","', $array);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE col IN ("'.$whereIn.'")';
```

Comment: Warning: this answer is DANGEROUS, allowing SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

try with this :

```
$whereIn = '("' . implode('","', $array) . '")';
```