# how to post form and get data from database in opencart

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

how to  post form  and get posted data to controller    and i don't know how to pass posted variable from controller to model  after getting i want to pass variables to views

controller.php

```
    if(isset($_POST["email"]))
    {
        $email=$_POST["email"];
    }
    $this->load->model('order/myorder');
 $data['data1']=$this->model_order_myorder->getOrder($email) ;


 view.php




    foreach ($data1 as $row) 
    {
   echo      echo   $row->order_id;

    }
model.php
<?php
class ModelOrderMyorder extends Model {

    public function getOrder($email) {

         $sql = "SELECT  *  FROM ".DB_PREFIX."order,".DB_PREFIX."order_product WHERE ".DB_PREFIX."order.email='$email'";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);

    return  $query ;
    }

}
```

Regards
Dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply pass the value as the parameter, e.g.

`$this->model_shipping_order->getordertracking($_POST['email']) {`

You should also escape the parameter in your query to prevent SQL injection e.g.

`WHERE email = '" . $this->db->escape($email) . "' ");`

Comment: WHERE email = '" . $this->db->escape($email) . "' "); is not working actually when i get  a single row it's working without errors but when i want get multiple value i kept in array  it's not working

Comment: can you see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29578031/illegal-string-offset-order-status-id-in-opencart  this coding not working i changed like that but still not working

Comment: So change your query to something more appropriate. Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7029777/1301076

Comment: Please do not completely change the question after an answer has been posted. Just create a new one.

Comment: i didn't change question i changed only code don't you see?

Comment: Yes, this is no longer related to "how to pass posted variable from controller to model". The question now seems to be "how do I rewrite my query to accept an array"

Comment: it the same has before but i tried with  different code it's not working  for some variables

Comment: i for "order_id"=>$result["order_id"] having int datatype in database so its getting like that

Comment: can you see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29578031/illegal-string-offset-order-status-id-in-opencart i  tick your answer