# Illegal string offset 'order_status_id' in opencart

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I am getting error `Illegal string offset 'order_status_id'` when I want to get loop data in view

Here's the code:

**controller.php**

```php
if (isset($_POST["email"])) {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
}

$this->load->model('order/myorder');
$data['data1'] = $this->model_order_myorder->getOrder($email) ;
```

**view.php**

```php
foreach ($data1 as $row) {
    echo echo $row->order_id;
}
```

**model.php**

```php
class ModelOrderMyorder extends Model {

    public function getOrder($email) {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".DB_PREFIX."order, ".DB_PREFIX."order_product WHERE ".DB_PREFIX."order.email = '$email'";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);

        return $query ;
    }

}
```

Still not getting it showing Trying to get property of non-object in view.

Comment: The error suggests the `order_status_id` field does not exist in `$result`. Your looping is odd. Because you are using `if (isset($result...` outside of the loop, `$result` will contain the last order in the set. I'd suggest doing a `var_dump($result);` just before that line, to see if it contains the data you expect.

Comment: it showing null if we keep var_dump($result); do you know how to pass query data to view  in a loop?

Comment: Try `var_dump($data)` instead. If that's NULL too, your query isn't getting any results. Note that you should be doing the query in your model, not the controller! To pass data to the view, you need to use (in your controller) `$this->data['YOUR_VARIABLE'] = 'whatever';`. Then in your view, you can use $YOUR_VARIABLE.

Comment: one thing i wrote query in controller for one row its working all details when i what to get second rows which match its not getting

Comment: ok i write model i will check

Comment: rjdown i wrote model and update code see  it's getting error

Comment: @rjdown cna you show me an example for this query `  $sql = "SELECT  *  FROM ".DB_PREFIX."order,".DB_PREFIX."order_product WHERE ".DB_PREFIX."order.email='$email'";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);    ' from model to controller and to pass to view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, if you want to iterate through all the order products for a given email (which is what I think you want) you should change the `getOrder()` method to return:

```php
 return $query->rows;
```

Then in the controller you need to change:

```php
$data['data1'] = $this->model_order_myorder->getOrder($email) ;
```

to

```php
$this->data['data1'] = $this->model_order_myorder->getOrder($email);
```

Finally, in your view, you'll be accessing an *array* not an *object* so you should lose the extra `echo` (assuming this is a typo) and change:

```php
echo   echo $row->order_id;
```

and get the index as:

```php
echo $row['order_id']
```

Also, in addition to the above, I'll suggest you utilize some of the methods and code conventions found in Opencart:

- When accessing the `$_POST` global you can use the sanitized
  version `$this->request->post`
- Your query fails to backtick the **order** table which can result
  in errors in you didn't set a prefix.  And you are not escaping
  `$email` which is a good idea for a number of reasons. Also, it makes
  things easy if you give your tables an alias. Finally, a join on the
  tables... so I might consider rewriting that query like this:

```php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "order_product op USING (order_id) WHERE o.email = '" . $this->db->escape($email) . "'";
```

To be honest, I'm not sure what results you're expecting from that query but bear in mind that if there are multiple products for an given order you will end up with multiple rows returned.

Just a few tips.. hopefully this is useful to you.