# Retrieve multiple IDs

Tags: php, mysqli

I have used `$mysqli->insert_id;`which returned a single ID. How can I retrieve IDs for multiple inserted rows in `mysqli`. Is there a solution?

Comment: Are you doing your INSERTs in a loop? If so, add the returned ID to an array on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: If you are using loop for inserting data then you can make an array from there only easily

Comment: @foxbeefly - No, I am not using loop for bulk insertion as I remember reading somewhere it slows down the performance.

Comment: Then how are you inserting multiple records? Post code please...

Answer (score 1):

Use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn IN ($ids);
```

Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/907821) and its thread for more info on the subject.

**EDIT:**
Misinterpreted the question. @DevLakshman has got the right idea.

Comment: Based on the inclusion of `$mysqli->insert_id;` I think @Aaron is trying to get the IDs of the records as they are inserted into the database, not return the records based on know IDs

Comment: I just reread the question and I'm afraid I misinterpreted it. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your next ids will be the succession of generated `$mysqli->insert_id` + the next n (number of inserts rows) as your statement is doing it in one transaction.

Comment: what if there are multiple inserts (transactions) happening at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing your insert query in loop then get the ids by `$mysqli->insert_id;` by writing it in loop or if manually writing many queries then write `$mysqli->insert_id;` correspondingly...