# PHP / MySQLi - array as bind_param

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am curious if there is a way to **bind array of parameters** at once?

In simple words, something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (?)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("<array>", $array_of_ids);
$stmt->execute();
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Not sure about that. TBC.

Comment: Sadly, no, Possible duplicate: [PHP/MySQL using an array in WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/php-mysql-using-an-array-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that as such but if you set up an array of params and values you could use a foreach loop something like

```
$params=array(
    ':id'=>1,
    ':cat'=>'bananas'
    ':type'=>100
);
foreach( $params as $param=>$value )$stmt->bind_param( $param,$value );
```

Answer (score 0):

Since PHP 5.6, this is possible with the ... operator (see also the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat)). This operator unpacks a list when calling a function, causing the list to act like multiple variables.

You could use the following:

```
$stmt->bind_param($types, ...$data);
```

This assumes that `$types` is a string containing the types for the data and `$data` a list containg the data for the query.