# MySql select field_1 where X = field_2 for all supplied Xs in a single query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How do I get all the 'name' column corresponding to the supplied ids in a single query ?

Suppose I have a php array like this `$ids = [ '1', '3', '7', '24', ... ];` then, is it possible to get the 'name' in the following table WHERE `$ids[i]='id'` in that table, all in a single query, or do I need to use `for` loop ?

```
CREATE TABLE `services` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `description` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`) USING BTREE
)
```

I am working with CodeIgniter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP/MySQL using an array in WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/php-mysql-using-an-array-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `where_in` for this

```
$ids = [ '1', '3', '7', '24', ... ];
$this->db->select('name');
$this->db->from('services');
$this->db->where_in('id', $ids);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `IN clause`

```
 SELECT * FROM `services` WHERE ID IN (".implode(',' , $ids).");
```

In case the dataType is varchar , make sure to add  `'` accordingly

```
 SELECT * FROM `services` WHERE ID IN ('".implode('','' , $ids)."');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use query bindings too, if the data array repeats :

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id = ? AND status = ? AND author = ?";

    $this->db->query($sql, array(3, 'live', 'Rick'));   
?>
```