# How to compare array and string with database in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a problem with the search data in the database whose value in the search of the array and string.

table (profile):

```
ID    Name status
1     Joe.     Free
2     Bill.      Not free
```

code:

```
$id = array('1', '2');
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM profile WHERE id = array and status='free' ");
```

I want check element of array and string (status) 1by1,  if get one who does not fit then it will return false. 
how the trick ?
thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP/MySQL using an array in WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/php-mysql-using-an-array-in-where-clause)

Comment: I was edit my question. Thanks

Comment: I do not understand the updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the = operator to check for multiple values, you need to use the [IN operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in):

```
SELECT name FROM profile WHERE id IN (1,3)
```

You can use php's [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function to create a comma separated list of an array's values.

In codeigniter you can use [where_in()](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) method:

> $this->db->where_in();
>
> Generates a `WHERE field IN ('item', 'item')` SQL query joined with AND
>   if appropriate
>
> `$names = array('Frank', 'Todd', 'James');
>   $this->db->where_in('username', $names); // Produces: WHERE username
>   IN ('Frank', 'Todd', 'James')`