# Search different columns by a separation of a comma

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that contains information such as names, email-addresses, numbers etc.
[image: My Database]

Let's pretend that I have 30 contacts by the same name but they all live in different cities . How do I split the comma and replace it with  `and ...`.

**Example**
`SELECT * WHERE name %$searchString% OR city %$searchString%...`

Now if `$searchString` contains comma

`SELECT * WHERE name %$searchString% OR city %$searchString%... AND SELECT * WHERE name %$searchString2% OR city %$searchString2%...`

The `$searchString2` contains information that's separated with comma.

**Update**

I want to search each row over and over again as many times as commas exist.
I'm sorry that I can't explain myself

Comment: `WHERE name %$searchString%` that should be `WHERE name LIKE '%$searchString%' OR ...` etc. If you're looking for exact finding, you'd use `WHERE name = '$searchString'` etc.

Comment: *"How do I split the comma"* - You'd explode/implode on it.

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51036322/2943403) is related (due to its similarity to the accepted answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on whether you want to return rows where name or city match the search values exactly (`=`), or rows where *any part of name or city* match the search values (`LIKE`).

Regardless of which one you need, you can start out by converting your search string into an array of strings like this:

```
$strings = array_map('trim', explode(',', $searchString));
```

The `array_map('trim'...` ensures that you don't try to match any spaces before or after the commas in your comma-separated search string.

Here are examples for how to execute your query using prepared statements in PDO. First, full matches using `IN`:

```
$phs = rtrim(str_repeat('?,', count($strings)),',');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE name IN ($phs) OR city IN ($phs)");
// double the string values to us in both INs
$values = array_merge($strings, $strings);
$stmt->execute($values);
```

and partial matches using `LIKE`:

```
$sql = '';
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    $sql .= ' name LIKE ? OR city LIKE ? OR';
    $values[] = $string;
    $values[] = $string;
}
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE' . rtrim($sql, ' OR'));
$stmt->execute($values);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use WHERE IN in SQL statement.

```
SELECT * WHERE name LIKE '%$searchString%' AND city IN ('city1', 'city2', 'city3'...)
```

Here is the good discussion on how to do it in PHP: [Passing an array to a query using a WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/php-mysql-using-an-array-in-where-clause)

Comment: `%$searchString%` strings need to be quoted. same for `IN (city1, city2, city3...)` those are strings, not integers as in the link you left here. This, as per your original answer http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35588188/1

Comment: Correct. Thanks! Fixed. Also, it's likely AND, not OR there.

Comment: You're welcome. However, it's a 2-part question. OP: *"How do I split the comma ... Now if $searchString contains comma"*

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

You will need to escape/clean the value of searchString.

```
<?php

// $searchString = "Cardiff,London,New York";

$SQL = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE ';

$searchStrings = explode(',',$searchString);

$SQLArray = array();

foreach($searchStrings as $searchString) {
    $SQLArray[] = "name LIKE '%$searchString%'";
    $SQLArray[] = "city LIKE '%$searchString%'";
}

$SQL .= implode(' OR ',$SQLArray);

// print $SQL;

?>
```

Comment: I've updated my question. sorry but that's not what i was looking for