# check if there istext after comma

Tags: php

I asked this question [about how to search different columns by a separation of a comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35588082/search-different-columns-by-a-separation-of-a-comma)
and I got answer.

My question for today is how  check if there is text after comma?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405493/get-everything-after-a-certain-character

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405493/get-everything-after-a-certain-character

Comment: like this `if((exist(character after comma))`

Comment: @FakhruddinUjjainwala I'm very sorry about this but how do I solve this problem?