# Query differences

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I had problem running a query and counting the results with this code:

```
$this->db->get_where('user_tb', array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password) );
$count = $this->db->count_all_results();
```

And it always return `1` even if the username and password are wrong.

Then I changed my code to:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_tb WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
$this->db->query($sql, array($username, $password));
$count = $this->db->count_all_results();
```

But the result is still the same.

Then my third and last try, I changed the code to:

```
$this->db->where('username', $username);
$this->db->where('password', $password);
$this->db->from('user_tb');
$count = $this->db->count_all_results();
```

Then it works. What are the differences between this three? Why is the last set of code works and the other two did not?

Answer (score 1):

In the 2nd line, you are using array , but in the 3rd line of your code you used single variable to compare column value thats why its working. 
To use array in query use `IN()` operator.

[Passing an array to a query using a WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/php-mysql-using-an-array-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 1):

Its because `$this->db->get_where();` and `$this->db->query();` executed the query and returned the sql result and ended sql execution. After above two call when you are calling `$this->db->count_all_results();` it is independent from above two calls. So it returns 1.  and in

```
$this->db->where('username', $username);
$this->db->where('password', $password);
$this->db->from('user_tb');
$count = $this->db->count_all_results();
```

Execution is done with above three line query builder. So it is working fine.

**Try this to see diffrence**

```
$result = $this->db->get_where('user_tb', array('username' => $username, 
          'password' => $password) );
$count = $this->db->count_all_results();

print_r($result); // you will see it contains all data related to your query.
```

Without any query when you use `$this->db->count_all_results();` which is equivalent to  `SELECT COUNT(*) AS numrows` and will return 1. In your above two cases happening same.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code in your model

```
    class Auth_login extends CI_Model
    {
        public function user_auth($username, $password)
        {
            $q = $this->db->where(['uname'=>$username, 'password'=>$password])
                          ->get('table'); //your table name

            if($q->num_rows())
            {
                return $q->row()->id; //primary key of returned row
            }
            else
            {
                return FALSE;
            }

        }
    }
```

Add this code to the controller to authenticate user

```
    $username = $this->input->post('user');
    $password = $this->input->post('pwd');
    $this->load->model('auth_login');
    $login_id = $this->auth_login->user_auth($username, $password);
     if($login_id)
        {
          $this->load->library('session');
          $this->session->set_userdata('id',$login_id);
          return redirect('user/dashboard');
        }                       
     else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('feedback','password not match!');
        }
        return $this->load->view('index_login');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello try this code and it return's number of affected rows

```
$this->db->get_where('user_tb', array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password) );
$query = $this->db->get();
$rowcount = $query->num_rows();
```

and let me know it's working or not.