# MySQL and PHP: how to fetch multiple ID's in an array containing the ID's

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have multiple ID's stored in a variable. This array can become long (+400 ID's). How do I fetch the data from these ID's in MySQL (PDO)?
I could do it via this:

```
"select * from info WHERE `id` IN ('1,2,3,4,5')"
```

But that's unsafe (SQL injection) and maybe not performant. Any suggestions to handle this problem?

Comment: Is your question how to prevent mysql injection or is there a problem with the code?

Comment: See the [answer here](https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/4dlcu6/i_want_to_set_up_a_form_that_will_send_its_input/d1srxmm?context=3) using `implode()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$in = join(',', array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));
$select = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM galleries
    WHERE id IN ($in);
SQL;
$statement = $pdo->prepare($select);
$statement->execute($ids);
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/php-mysql-using-an-array-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 1):

take out single quote from the content `'1,2,3,4,5'` this checks the complete value under ID.

so use it without single quotes as the ID column is numeric, `1,2,3,4,5` this will separate each value.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that id field is INTEGER so please remove the apostrophes and new query will be like,

```
select * from info WHERE `id` IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

the other hand at PHP side for instance,

```
$idList = explode(',', $_GET['id_list']);
$idList = implode(',', array_unique(array_map('intval', $idList)));

$query = "select * from info WHERE `id` IN ($idList)";
```

and please check max allowed selector in `IN`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
"select * from info WHERE `id` IN (1,2,3,4,5)"
```

Including single quotes forces whole value to be considered as single string.

If you have value in array then just write it as

```
$query = "select * from info WHERE `id` IN (implode(',', array_map('intval', json_decode('[' . $ids . ']', true))))" ;
```

Comment: This looks like it would be vulnerable to SQL injection issues.

Comment: We usually sanitise input before sending to model or executing query. So it's not vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: That's not sufficient for an answer, in my view - if it doesn't use parameter binding or explicit untainting, then it is vulnerable. Your readers don't have the external (unstated) sanitisation code that you do.

Comment: @halfer i have updated :-)