# SQL - syntax error

Tags: php, sql

can you see what is wrong on this query? I have been watching it for really long time and I can't see it.

> ERROR: 
>       You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>       check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
>       for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 1

```
$sql="SELECT country_name FROM countries WHERE country_id IN (";
    foreach($cartContentVsDatabase as $key => $val){
      $sql.= $key['country_id'].",";        
    }
    ")";
```

Comment: Please show what the resulting query is after it is set.

Comment: learn about prepared statements

Comment: `echo $sql;` after your loop, u will get the error

Comment: ")"; --> $SQL.=")"; and you have to remove the last `,`

Comment: You're going to have a trailing `,` after the last country_id

Comment: Should use var_dump($sql); to see your query correctly and where your problem is.

Comment: You'll have a trailing comma after the IN (...) list, you're not appending the last closing bracket to the string, you seem to be trying to use an array key as an array. Take your pick.

Comment: You didn't concatenate the last part of the string, as @Jens said

Comment: Don't edit your question to include the answer that worked.  Instead, accept the answer that helped you below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,
change `")";` to  `$sql.=  ")";`

```
    $array_count = count($cartContentVsDatabase);
    $temp_count = 0;
    $sql="SELECT country_name FROM countries WHERE country_id IN (";
    foreach($cartContentVsDatabase as $key => $val){
       $temp_count++;
      if($array_count < $temp_count)
      {
           $sql.= $val['country_id'];   
      }
      else
      {
          $sql.= $val['country_id'].",";   
      }

    }
    $sql.=  ")";
```

Comment: This solves 1 out of the ±6 problems the OP has in their code. This alone will not fix it.

Comment: There's still extra `,` in the end

Comment: And `$key` cannot be array.

Answer (score 2):

Some issues:

- You have a trailing comma in your country list,
- countries should be quoted as strings,
- you are accessing the values from the key instead of the value part of the array elements.
- you have a dangling closing parenthesis, which does nothing.
- You should not even inject country strings, as that makes your code vulnerable for code injection: use prepared statements.

Here is code you could use:

```
// first put the countries in an array
foreach($cartContentVsDatabase as $key => $val){
  $countries[] = $val['country_id'];  
}
// create a list of `?`: one for every country
$in = join(',', array_fill(0, count($countries), '?'));

// use that in the query
$sql="SELECT country_name FROM countries WHERE country_id IN ($in)";

// Prepare the statement (this is PDO syntax)
$statement = $pdo->prepare($select);

// Pass the countries as parameter values, and execute
$statement->execute($countries);
```

See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/907806/5459839) for more on prepared statements in the context of this `in (...)` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your life a lot easier by

```
$sql= "SELECT country_name FROM countries WHERE country_id IN (".implode(",",array_column($cartContentVsDatabase,"country_id")). ")";
```

You can (and probably should) use a prepared query e.g. like the one below:

```
$sql= "SELECT country_name FROM countries WHERE country_id IN (".implode(",",array_fill(0,count($cartContentVsDatabase),"?")). ")";
```

and then bind the contents of `$cartContentVsDatabase` when you execute.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are not concatenate `")";` properly at the end. you can also store data into array and than use `implode()` for comma separated values like:

**Example:**

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT country_name FROM countries ";

$countries = array();
foreach($cartContentVsDatabase as $key => $val){
  $countries[] = $val['country_id'];  // store country id in your array
}

if(count($countries) > 0){
     $countrylist = implode("','",$countries); // implode all country list with comma.    
     $sql .= "WHERE country_id IN ('$countrylist')";
}    
echo $sql; // print your query.

?>
```

Still i don't know, `$key['country_id']` is the correct one or not, i think this should be `$val['country_id']`.