# How to make each element a separate string after implode - PHP

Tags: php

I have an array like this:

```
$myArray = array(1,2,3,5,4,7,8);
```

I want to select records where id is IN() $myArray. how do i achieve something like this in the SQL? **IN('1','2','3','5','4','7','8')**  so that each of the element is like a separate string

what am currently doing is not helping:

```
$SQL = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE id IN(".IMPLODE(',',$myArray).")";
```

Comment: try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/907821/5608642

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$SQL = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE id IN('" .implode("','", $myArray) . "')";
                                         ^            ^ ^                ^
```