# MySQL using IN () with array

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays

I have been looking at using IN(array) and I have seen a lot of examples here such as [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/907821/8410541) and [this](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/return-mysql-query-that-matches-php-array) but for some reason my query does not return anything. I am making an android application for job advertising, I have a table with all the jobs in my database and all jobs have a typewhich can be any of these `"Advert","Consultancy","Freelance","Full Time","Internship","Part Time","Temporary"`. On the android side user selects which `job type/s` they wish to view and I compile a JSONArray and convert it to a string using `toString()` then send it to the server side, the typical array looks like 
`["Advert","Consultancy","Freelance","Full Time","Internship","Part Time","Temporary"]` When received its converted to a `php` array

```
 `$types = json_decode('["Advert","Consultancy","Freelance","Full Time","Internship","Part Time","Temporary"]', TRUE);`
```

then finally

```
$match_list = join(",", $types);
$result =  $this->conn->prepare("SELECT j.id, u.username, j.title, j.description,j.category, j.type, j.submissionDeadline, j.link, j.datecreated FROM job_tb j JOIN user_tb u ON u.id = j.userFk WHERE DATE(j.submissionDeadline) > DATE(NOW()) AND j.type IN (?) ORDER BY j.datecreated DESC");
$result->bind_param("s", $match_list);
$result->execute();
$response["jobs"] = array();

$result->bind_result($id, $username, $title, $description, $category, $type, $submissionDeadline, $link, $datecreated);
while($row = $result->fetch()) 
{
    $job = array();
    $job["id"] = $id;
    $job["username"] = $username;
    $job["title"] = $title;
    $job["description"] = $description;
    $job["category"] = $category;
    $job["type"] = $type;
    $job["submissionDeadline"] = $submissionDeadline;  
    $job["link"] = $link; 
    $job["dateCreated"] = $datecreated;   
    $response["jobs"][] =  $job;

}
```

Unfortunately nothing is returned but when I pass a single job type item array like `["Part Time"]` it returns all jobs of type `Part Time` so what could be the problem?

Comment: It is all bound as 1 value. You need a placeholder for each value, and you then need to bind each value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)

Comment: Post the result var_dump($match_list); here please so we can see what it contains.

Comment: @Nic its `Advert,Consultancy,Freelance,Full Time,Internship,Part Time,Temporary`

Comment: So the query becomes .... IN (Advert,Consultancy,Freelance,Full Time,Internship,Part Time,Temporary).  You need to quote each item.   Look at this https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#in  there is an example of how to join + quote your array elements.

Comment: or this: 
$inQuery = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($ids), '?'));   from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition.  You are very close!

Comment: okay let me check it out