# MySQL Select on array

Tags: mysql, arrays, select

I have an array which contains integer values and I would like to do a select on my MySQL database that gives me the datasets that do include the values in that array

```
$array[0] = 1
$array[1] = 3
$array[2] = 9
```

And my SQL should be something like

```
Select * from table where value = Array
```

Does that work somehow?

Comment: post the schema and values for this and the expected results

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/passing-an-array-to-a-query-using-a-where-clause

Comment: *"Does that work somehow?"* - Did you try it/something?

Comment: You're looking for `IN`