# Search from string in mysql using php array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have absolutely no idea where to start.

I have a table called "users" in my database called "database":

```
NAME | POINTS
John 24
Marrie 32
Moritz 11
Adam 99
Hans 34
Monica 58
```

I also have this

```
    <?php
    $users = array("Adam", "Hans", "Monica");
    ?>
```

What I would like to do is:
Connect to mysql table "users" then database called "database", search for the names mentioned in the array $users and give me the list of their points (without names).

SO it should echo

```
99
34
58
```

Comment: this is both unclear and too broad. Read up on the many tutorials and manuals then edit your post to contain what you had problems with.

Comment: i don't know how to use php arrays with mysql commands

Comment: A good tutorial is e.g. on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp)

Comment: Also, although it's a bit high-brow, see about using IN() in conjunction with prepared statements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing an array to a query using a WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/passing-an-array-to-a-query-using-a-where-clause)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using IN with MySQL:

```
$users = array('Adam', 'Hans', 'Monica');
$users_joined = join("','",$users);   
$sql = "SELECT POINTS FROM users WHERE NAME IN ('$users_joined')";
```

More information: [Stackoverflow - passing an array in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/passing-an-array-to-a-query-using-a-where-clause)