# PHP mysqli SELECT * from my_table WHERE id = array_of_ids

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have been using this site for years now and this is the first time I'm asking a question here, so kinda scared right now :D

Here's what my problem is, I have got two tables. In table_a I got three columns and in table_b I got 5. So the setup right now looks something like this:

```
       table_a

| r_id | foo   | bar |
+------+-------+-----+
| 1    | dude  | 5   |
+------+-------+-----+
| 2    | homie | 6   |
+------+-------+-----+
| 3    | bro   | 7   |
+------+-------+-----+

       table_b

| id | ada   | rea | lm   | cor  |
+----+-------+-----+------+------+
| 5  | ching | ink | jk   | 32.4 |
+----+-------+-----+------+------+
| 1  | momo  | pal | lmao | 95.5 |
+----+-------+-----+------+------+
| 6  | mama  | pen | lol  | 26.9 |
+----+-------+-----+------+------+
| 4  | chac  | pin | fun  | 91.2 |
+----+-------+-----+------+------+
| 7  | chim  | lap | funk | 82.4 |
+----+-------+-----+------+------+
| 9  | cho   | kil | fin  | 38.1 |
+----+-------+-----+------+------+
```

Now what I'm trying to do is to get all the data from table_a and then only get `lm` from table_b. I'm getting all the data from table_a like this:

`SELECT r_id, foo, bar from table_a`

I need to use the ids I get from `bar` column to get `lm` from table_b. So is there a way I can pass an array to only get the data based on the ids in an array? If not, then what would be the most efficient way to get those?

The output I'm expecting is `jk, lol, funk`. 
Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: try where IN(array of ids)

Comment: It's probably better to use `inner join` for the solution

Comment: You should inner join

Comment: If you want to stick to  using an array and an in clause - then it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/passing-an-array-to-a-query-using-a-where-clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be looking at using a [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) to link the two tables together in 1 query...

```
SELECT  r_id, foo, bar, lm
    FROM table_a 
    JOIN table_b on bar = id
```

Comment: Although you can do almost anything in PHP - SQL can make your life so much easier so worth taking some time to have a play with it.

Answer (score 1):

For that you can try WHERE IN feature of SQL.

```
SELECT lm from table_b WHERE id IN(ARRAY_OF_IDS)
```

Or you can also use join to achieve this

```
Select tale_a.*, tale_b.lm from tale_a inner join table_b ON tale_a.bar=tale_b.id
```

Comment: Thanks! that was pretty quick. So how would I do it using PHP. 
$bar_ids = array(5,6,7)
$query = 'SELECT lm from table_b WHERE id IN($bar_ids)'
and then run the query ?

Comment: Yes, you can use this variable in it. $query = 'SELECT lm from table_b WHERE id IN($bar_ids)'. Or if bar is related with table_b id column then you can use joins too.

Comment: Thanks!! I tried Nigel's solution and it worked as expected. However, I'm going to keep this array thing in mind for future stuff. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

try `inner join`

```
SELECT a.r_id, a.foo, a.bar, b.lm  from table_a as a inner join table_b as b on b.id=a.bar
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not join?

```
select group_concat(lm) as lm_list
from table_b b
inner join table_a a on b.id = a.bar
```

You can use the GROUP_CONCAT() function, with this you would get `jk, lol, funk` otherwise you would get 3 rows each of one `lm` value,

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`INNER JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

```
 SELECT tale_a.r_id, tale_a.foo, tale_a.bar ,table_b.lm 
 FROM tale_a
 INNER JOIN table_b
 ON tale_a.bar=table_b.id
```

**Note:** It returns all columns from `table_a` and only one column from `table_b`

**Resultant Output:**

```
| r_id | foo   | bar | lm  |
+------+-------+-----+-----+
| 1    | dude  | 5   | jk  |
+------+-------+-----+-----+
| 2    | homie | 6   |lol  |
+------+-------+-----+-----+
| 3    | bro   | 7   |funk |
+------+-------+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have array of IDs having IDs.
So first make a comma separated string of that array of IDs like this:

```
ids_str = implode("," $ARRAY_OF_IDS);
```

and then use that `ids_str` in `IN` os mysql query like below:

```
SELECT lm from table_b WHERE id IN( ids_str )
```