# I need help converting an array to a string to use it in a sql statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, implicit-conversion

I need help converting this array to a string

```
$thingOne = connecting::query('SELECT thing1 FROM accounts WHERE username=:user_name', array(':user_name'=>$user_name));
```

So I can use it in this statement

```
$thing= connecting::query('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE thing1=:thingOne AND username!=: user_name,                 array(':thingOne'=>$thingOne),array(':user_name'=>$ran_dom));
```

I'm just trying to get all occurrences of `thingOne` in the accounts table where it's not the same user.

I've already tried using `var_export`, and `json_encode`, and they both don't convert it when I print it after using those functions, I still get the raw array data whether using `print_r` or `echo`. And when I use `implode` nothing prints. I am really confused where to go from here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing an array to a query using a WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/passing-an-array-to-a-query-using-a-where-clause)

Comment: thanks i'll check it out

Comment: In the second example you are missing quote `'`

Comment: idk that link isn't working for me

Comment: Instead of using that join function since it doesn't return anything I'm using json_encode like this : $stringOne = json_encode($thingOne);

Comment: and then I use the In clause like this : $matchThing = connecting::query('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE thing1 IN("$stringOne")');