# Getting a bind_param() error in my SQL statement with IN array?

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot seem to understand why I am getting error: `mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement`
I followed this example:
[Passing an array to a query using a WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/passing-an-array-to-a-query-using-a-where-clause)
if you have any ideas that would be awesome!

```
$sql="SELECT pid,title,description,location FROM jobs WHERE status='o'";
if(isset($_POST['category'])){
    $category_filter = join(',', array_fill(0, count($_POST['category']), '?'));
    $sql .= " AND category IN ('.$category_filter.')";
}

$sql.="ORDER BY job_date DESC";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param(str_repeat('s', count($_POST['category'])), ...$_POST['category']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($pid,$title,$description,$location);
```

Comment: You should have mismatched quotes in `$sql .= " AND category IN ('.$category_filter.')";` it should be `$sql .= ' AND category IN ('.$category_filter.')';`

Comment: wow what the heck? can you please explain that to me? how must that statement be with single quotes, while the first statement and the last does not need to be?

Comment: I suggest you `echo $sql` in both cases to see what you're actually getting. In your existing code, it's a string with a lot of `?` in it, which is *not* a set of placeholders, hence the `bind_param` error

Comment: Interesting, with single quotes I get  `AND category IN (?,?)ORDER BY` while with double quotes i get  `AND category IN ('.?,?.')ORDER BY`

Comment: how does a double quote make a period in this situation?

Comment: Note it would have been just as valid to write `$sql .= " AND category IN (".$category_filter.")";` the requirement was just to match the quotes.

Comment: Because in your existing code there is just one string and the `.`'s are characters in it, not concatenation operators.

Comment: ohhhh i see, that makes sense now, i never thought about that. thanks! also good tip on echoing the SQL statement, never thought to do that.