# PHP - Split a String into parts with quote marks

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, string

I have a string such as this "`$names = "name1,name2`".

I am going to be writing these names into an SQL `IN` statement such as "... `IN('name1','name2')`";

How can I seperate the `"name1,name2"` into `'name1' , 'name2'`?

This is essential for the SQL statement to work correctly.

Comment: You could combine `explode` and `implode` function

Comment: `php explode string` query will show __millions__ of answers.

Comment: thanks guys @Rocky, im really new to PHP. any example code for my situation?

Comment: If you're new I'd suggest you follow @u_mulder 's comment

Comment: @Rocky ive used explode to get them into an array before. But they do not have the quote marks around them in the array and it does not print correctly into the SQL statement.?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/passing-an-array-to-a-query-using-a-where-clause.

Answer (score 1):

Was able to use explode and implode as described by the comments. 
Then ran into the problem of a space before one of my first names, where I had to remove the whitespace.

Works 100%!

```
 foreach ($usernames as $details) {
        $names = $details->meta_value;
        $sortednames = preg_replace('/\s*,\s*/', ',', $names);
        $explodednames = explode(',',$sortednames);
        echo "explodednames".$explodednames;
        $implodednames = implode("','",$explodednames);
        }
```