# How to check and pull data of multiple emails from an account table?

Tags: mysql, arrays

I have an array of about 1,000 emails like `['a@a.com', 'b@b.com', ..., 'zz@zz.com']` that I need to check. If an email exists in the account table, I need to pull the first and last name of the row that matches the email in the account table.

The account table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE account (
   id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
   first_name VARCHAR(255),
   last_name VARCHAR(255)
);
```

What is the best way to achieve this without looping through the array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing an array to a query using a WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/passing-an-array-to-a-query-using-a-where-clause)

Answer (score 0):

First, extract all values that matches the emails using `IN()` syntax.

Second, `GROUP` the values by email to remove duplicates.

Third, get only the lowest value (the first) via aggregation `MIN()`.

Fourth, self `JOIN` with filtered `id`

```
SELECT * FROM account t1
JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(id) FROM account
    WHERE email IN ('a@a.com', 'b@b.com', ...)
    GROUP BY email
) t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
```