# Convert String containing commas to array

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to convert a String

```
$string = "'1', '2', '3'";`
```

to an array

```
$array = array($string);
```

By doing so it gives me an error when trying to fetch data on MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM name WHERE id NOT IN ( '" . implode( "', '" , $array) . "' ) LIMIT 10
```

However, if I manually set the array as `$array = array('1', '2', '3')` it doesn't give an error when fetching a data, is there a way to convert the string to the array so the fetching doesn't give out an error? Because what I am trying to do is some data will be going to be passed to this file, where it will be fetched as a String, but later want to convert it to an array. I also tried removing the quotation mark from the String and it still gives the same error `str_replace('"', "", $string);` using this inside of the array.

Comment: You need to escape special characters in the implode.

Comment: would it not just be `not in (str_replace("'", "", $string))`

Comment: Why not just `SELECT * FROM name WHERE id NOT IN ( ' . $string . ' ) LIMIT 10`?

Comment: Or using prepared statements - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/passing-an-array-to-a-query-using-a-where-clause

Comment: @Nathan_Sav since I am using php this method conflicts with all the quotation marks and php gives out an error

Comment: @GuidoFaecke this way for some reason it doesn't fetch any data

Comment: If you do `$array = array($string);` you get an array with that string as its only member. Use e.g. [explode](https://www.php.net/explode) or [preg_split](https://www.php.net/preg_split).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you remove the quotes around the id's, assuming the `id` column is a integer column

```
$string = "'1', '2', '3'"; 
$string = str_replace("'", '', $string);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM name WHERE id NOT IN ( " . implode(",", explode(',',$string)) . ") LIMIT 10 ";
echo $sql;
```

RESULT

```
SELECT * FROM name WHERE id NOT IN ( 1, 2, 3) LIMIT 10
```

Of course a simpler way would be to simply do

```
$string = "'1', '2', '3'"; 
$string = str_replace("'", '', $string);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM name WHERE id NOT IN ( $string ) LIMIT 10 ";
```

Comment: I don't think so ;) -- `implode` without a second argument results an empty separator, so `echo implode([1,2,3]);` results in `123` (**NOT** `1,2,3`). But since `$string` does not contain the separator you are using in your explode (`','`, but string contains `', '`), the original version of `$string` is used in the query.

Comment: @boppy I am actually still learning sql and php, your point may be true and I will definitely keep on looking into it, but this answer did get the job done and I am able to fetch the data I am intending to. But thanks for your answer! I will also look into your answer and hopefully learn more about it.

Comment: @RiggsFolley: No, it produces the desired output by accident! Check: `explode("','",$string)` results in an array containing ONE Element. Joining it will produce the original string. Even exploding by `','` CANNOT work, because it will not catch the `'`s at the beginning and end of the input.

Comment: @boppy Yea you are right, amended

Comment: It works now, but explode+implode with the same separator will always result in the final string being exactly the input string...

Comment: Oh lord, I must need more caffine :) A simple amendment I hope will clear this up

Comment: Even `NOT IN ( '1', '2', '3' )` would work, which is what you get if the original `$string` is left untouched and just slapped in, ie. `NOT IN ( $string )` without any of the hoopla. MySQL simply converts the queried string-numbers to integers, assuming integer column, and then compares.