# select distinct where id in a list of values - gives me a wrong result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

```
$('#btnmails').on('click', function(){
    let ids = $.map($('.atitle'), (e) => $(e).attr('data-id'));
    ids = JSON.stringify(ids);
    console.log(ids);  // ["26","25","24","23","22","21"]
    $.post('pro.php', {fn: 'btn_mails', args: [ids]}, function(data){
        console.log(data);  // 0 - but it is not true
    });
});
```

**pro.php**

```
function btn_mails($ids){
    global $db;
    $sq = "select distinct mail from clients where id in ('" . $ids . "')";
    $st = $db->prepare($sq);
    $st->execute();
    $arr = $st->fetchAll();
    echo count($arr);
}
```

I have all six ids in table and each of them with a distinct mail
so result should be 6 and not 0
pls help

Comment: I would recommend following https://stackoverflow.com/a/23641033/1213708 as it protects you from SQL injection.

Comment: If you expand `where id in ('" . $ids . "')"` you can see it's a string:  `where id in ('...')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem is in your php function

Probably `$ids` is an array so you have to transform it in a string using `implode`

like this

```
function btn_mails($ids){
    global $db;
    $sq = "select distinct mail from clients where id in (" . implode(', ', $ids) . ")";
    $st = $db->prepare($sq);
    $st->execute();
    $arr = $st->fetchAll();
    echo count($arr);
}
```

Comment: `$str = implode(', ', $ids);` and `$sq = "select distinct mail from prijave where id in (" . $str . ")";` works - without `stringify` on client side. Thanks a lot